# R - Lattice - Change color of regression line

Tags: r

I am trying to change the regression line color to red. Right now everything is plotting blue.

```
library(lattice)

xyplot(ROC1.spx ~ ROC1.vix, data=newdf,
xlab = "VIX 1 Day % Change",
ylab = "S&P500 1 Day % Change",
grid = TRUE,
type = c("p","r"))
```

To plot the regression line on the chart I used type = c("p","r")).

Open to other methods if need be, the code above produces this output.

[image: xyplot]

Any assistance with changing regression line to red is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to:

```
type = c("p","r"),col.line = "red",
```

col.line ="color", :)